# Katello subscription-manager: wrong Yum repo URL?

Tags: yum, satellite, katello

I'm using RH Satellite 6, and have built a katello capsule. I've synced a very specific environment/content view over to the capsule.

I'm trying to build a node from the capsule to test things out, and it seems to have pulled down something wrong at the start and is refusing to fix itself!

Useful output:

```
[root@captest ~]# subscription-manager environments --org=MYORG --username=admin
+-------------------------------------------+
          Environments
+-------------------------------------------+
Name:        VALIDATION/VALIDATION
Description:

Name:        VAGRANT/VALIDATION
Description:

Name:        Library/VALIDATION
Description:

Name:        POC/RHEL7
Description:

Name:        Library/RHEL7
Description:

Name:        POC/RHEL6
Description:

Name:        Library/RHEL6
Description:

Name:        Library
Description:
```

The one I want is `VALIDATION/VALIDATION`, which is synced to the capsule.

However:

[root@captest ~]# subscription-manager repos

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
    Available Repositories in /etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo
+----------------------------------------------------------+
Repo ID:   rhel-7-server-optional-rpms
Repo Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server - Optional (RPMs)
Repo URL:  https://capsule-core-1.intranet.net/pulp/repos/MYORG/POC/RHEL7/content/dist/rhel/server/7/$releasever/$bas
           earch/optional/os
Enabled:   0
```

...which appears to be using the POC/RHEL7 environment.

Any ideas? I'm sure I've tried rebuilding the node and checking the environment, but I'll happily try that again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seemed to be under *Content Hosts* - in Satellite, under Hosts -> Content Hosts, the node in question had an environment that did not match that assigned to it from the "Edit Host" window (where one can assign puppet classes and the like).

I think what happened is that there was an error during host creation in Foreman, and it reset the environment to the defaults for that hostgroup. When I clicked "submit" again, I'd not noticed that the environment was wrong. This meant the initial environment for the Content was wrong, and as such the repos got pulled in incorrectly.

**Update**: Also, the "Activation Key" that was being used was assigning the wrong environment! Check that too, future googlers!